# pivot_longer with pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe

```
> data <- 
structure(list(a = 1:2, b = c(2L, 2L), c = 1:2, d = c(1L, 4L)), row.names = c("a", 
"b"), class = "data.frame")

> data
  a b c d
a 1 2 1 1
b 2 2 2 4
```

I want to have all pairwise comparisons in long format using pivot_longer from tidyverse

The results shoud look like this

```
compA  compB    value
     a      a      1
     a      b      2
     b      a      2
     b      b      2
     c      a      1
     c      b      2
     d      a      1
     d      b      4
```

I have tried:

```
   data %>% pivot_longer(cols=everything(),names_to=c("compA","compB"),values_to="value")

Error: If you supply multiple names in `names_to` you must also supply one of `names_sep` or `names_pattern`.
```

How can I obtain the desired output with tidyverse pivot_longer ??
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add rownames as column and then use `pivot_longer`

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

data %>%  rownames_to_column('row') %>% pivot_longer(cols = -row)

#  row   name  value
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 a     a         1
#2 a     b         2
#3 a     c         1
#4 a     d         1
#5 b     a         2
#6 b     b         2
#7 b     c         2
#8 b     d         4
```